# PHP system commands while running by cron

Tags: php, linux, cron

Direct to questions 
While running php scripts via cron how are the OS(linux) commands are interpreted when using functions like exec,system,shell_exec .... 
Seems sometime i need to provide full path like :

```
   #!/usr/bin/env php
  <?php
    foreach($ips as $insert)
   {
     exec("/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -s {$insert} -j ACCEPT");
     echo 'Allowing ' . $insert . " in iptables\r\n";
   }
  ?>
```

and sometimes no need to provide  absolute path

```
       #!/usr/bin/env php
  <?php
    foreach($ips as $insert)
   {
     exec("iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -s {$insert} -j ACCEPT");
     echo 'Allowing ' . $insert . " in iptables\r\n";
   }
  ?>
```

Seems related to cron env pathes
What is the best method for using relative path for os command rather providing the full path ?
Does running script like

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /scripts/iptables.php
```

make any difference to ENV variables path ?
Using absolute path make it harder for script to work on different os and distros

Answer (score 0):

All cronjobs are run in a very limited environment where most environment variables aren't actually set. This includes the PATH variable, which is why you generally need to specify the full path to all commands run during cron jobs.

You can solve this by setting the PATH environment variable yourself above the declaration of your cron job. This is an example:

```
PATH="/sbin:/usr/bin"
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /scripts/iptables.php
```

You can find more information [here](http://krisjordan.com/essays/timesaving-crontab-tips).

Comment: Thank you , this was description i was looking for